# Adding Fancybox to this Elastislider : http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index3.html

Tags: slider, fancybox

I need to add the new responsive fancybox popup to this slider http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index3.html

does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In jquery.elastislide.js line 265, replace:

```
// item click event
this.jQueryitems.bind(‘click.elastislide’, function( event ) {
instance.options.onClick( jQuery(this) );
return false;
});
with
// item click event
this.jQueryitems.bind(‘click.elastislide’, function( event ) {
instance.options.onClick( jQuery(this) );
//return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a post on our website regarding a bug relating to lightbox/elastislide. see here: http://www.think-creative.co.uk/blog/68/getting-a-lightbox-to-work-with-elastislide

you will need to add "onClick:null" into your options on the page in order for the lightbox part to work with the elastislide.